# Compiling a cuda code which does not support c++11 and a .cxx file requires a c++11 with an vexcl example

Tags: c++, cuda, opencl, gpgpu

I am new to gpu technology and was exploring the vexCL library for GPU computing with OpenCL and cuda backend.I aksed a question that was specific to the specific library.

I am modifying the question so that it can be treated as a general question. The problem was basically how to compile cuda version which do not support -std=c++11 and .cxx file that requires std=c++11 features.

E.g. If you check the vexcl tutorials there are a tutorial program that uses both thrust.cu and thrust.cpp . Now as I have solved it I just want to mention the way to solve it in the following paragraph:

1) First compile the .cpp file like e.g

```
   g++ -c -std=c++11 -o ts1.o -I${VEXCL_ROOT} -I${CUDA_INCLUDES} -DVEXCL_BACKEND_CUDA thrust-sort.cpp
```

2) and the compile the .cu file

```
nvcc -c -o ts2.o thrust-sort.cu
```

3) Compile the object files together

```
 nvcc -o ts ts1.o ts2.o -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lcuda
```

But with proper linking with libraries.

This is how I solved the problem

Comment: You should [open an issue](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/issues/new) on VexCL issue tracker.

Comment: Can I get the down vote removed now? This is very strange. I can not even post a new question. I can not even comment in any question . So, there is no way to increase my reputation. I have only asked very few questions so far in Stackoverflow and before getting used to the rule of the site someone just down voted and now I just can not use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thrust-sort.cu and thrust-sort.cpp are parts of the same program. Those are split because nvcc, until version 7 (which has just came out), did not support C++11. So you need to compile both of those (with `-c` flag) and then link them together. Second, you cannot mix backends in the same binary in vexcl. And, since this particular example uses thrust, the backend has to be CUDA. So the compilation commands should be

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -o ts1.o -I${VEXCL_ROOT} -I${CUDA_INCLUDES} -DVEXCL_BACKEND_CUDA thrust-sort.cpp
nvcc -c -o ts2.o thrust-sort.cu
nvcc -o ts ts1.o ts2.o -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lcuda
```

The CMakeLists.txt that is provided with the library should deal with these issues out of the box for you.

Comment: I got a run-time error message

Comment: I posted in the github as you suggested. Thank you very much for your help and quick response.

Comment: I am deleting the post from here as this is not following the standard here. Thank you for help and next time onwards I will raise issues in vexcl github